# How do I bring the last conversations from a rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My database looks like this:

An user has many conversations, a conversation has 2 users and many message.

Given an user I want to bring the last conversations that message has been send, but I don't know what is the best approach? Do I need more data in my tables?

```
 conversation table

 id | sender_id | reciver_id 

 message table

 id | text | user_id | conversation|id
```

```
module Types
  class ConversationType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :sender_id, Integer, null: true
    field :receiver_id, Integer, null: true
    field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: true
  end
end


module Types
  class MessageType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :body, String, null: true
    field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: true
  end
end


module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String, null: true
    field :messages, [Types::MessageType], null: false
    field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null: true
  end
end
```

The migrations

```
class CreateConversation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :conversations do |t|
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :receiver_id

      t.datetime :deleted_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :conversation, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.datetime :deleted_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean with "had movement"?

Comment: Wouldn't a new message indicate 'movement' in the conversation?